# History of letter $h$ in the formulation of differentiability

Tags: soft-question, notation

$f$ is differentiable in $x$ if $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$ exists. Why is the letter $h$ typically used here, what it the history of this? I feel that $\delta$ or $\Delta$ for example would better fit.

Comment: Horizontal change?

Comment: It's so used in G.H. Hardy's _Course in Pure Mathematics_ of 1908, but I'm sure its much older than that.

Comment: This answer seems to give a good history. <https://mathoverflow.net/a/95290>